# Imagebuttons gap

Tags: asp.net, css

I don't have any CSS on the page.
If i place 2 imagebuttons control in 2 lines of code like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnVoteUp" Height="16px" Width="16px" runat="server"  ImageUrl="images/thumbs_up.gif" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' CommandName="VoteUp" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnVoteDown" Height="16px" Width="16px" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="images/thumbs_down.gif" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' CommandName="VoteDown" />
```

I get a gap as seen on the picture (top row).
If i place 2 imagebuttons control in 1 line like this:

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnVoteUp" Height="16px" Width="16px" runat="server"   ImageUrl="images/thumbs_up.gif" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' CommandName="VoteUp" /><asp:ImageButton ID="btnVoteDown" Height="16px" Width="16px" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="images/thumbs_down.gif" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' CommandName="VoteDown" />
```

I don't get the gap as seen on the picture (second row).

[alt text http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/3817/83160966.jpg](http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/3817/83160966.jpg)

How can i remove this gap without placing imagebuttons in one line?

THis is the generated markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Untitled Page
</title></head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Default2.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTEwMTIxNjc1NjlkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYCBQlidG5Wb3RlVXAFC2J0blZvdGVEb3duh1gAW23G9CSHTqWHtf1jVb+auJw=" />
</div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAwLQ9PKkAgKUxN/UAgLruYmsBra/X3TDmu9s+nIDB4+xY93e6ZqR" />
</div>
    <div>
        <input type="image" name="btnVoteUp" id="btnVoteUp" src="images/thumbs_up.gif" style="height:16px;width:16px;border-width:0px;" />
        <input type="image" name="btnVoteDown" id="btnVoteDown" src="images/thumbs_down.gif" style="height:16px;width:16px;border-width:0px;" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does the actual generated HTML look like when you run this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap them in an element with a `font-size` of `0px` - that will shrink the space down to a nothing in Firefox, and `1px` in IE. It's possibly not ideal, but would work.

Answer (score 2):

When you split them up in two lines you'll get whitespace between the controls and a whitespace character is rendered. If you place them on the same line with no whitespace between them there is no whitespace rendered.

Don't think there is any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post but anyone having this problem can try the following if just trying to remove the gap between `asp:imagebutton`'s.

Insert a `ImageAlign="Left"` or right depending on where you are placing the object. Ensure this is within the `asp:imagebutton` element i.e.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Img/BUTTONS/button1.jpg" ImageAlign="Left" />

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Img/button2.jpg" ImageAlign="Left" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check the generated HTML to get an idea how's the images are being rendered, I would recommend putting the two asp:imagebuttons inside a div with style='white-space:nowrap'

Comment: How does specifying nowrap on whitespace cause whitespace to be collapsed?

Comment: Anthony's right, this won't help: "nowrap" Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a <br /> tag is encountered (from http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_white-space.asp) - so there will still be one space between the two images.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS then

You can format the whole document in the source view.

Go to

***Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document***

The shortcut is

*Ctrl K + Ctrl D*

This will remove all the whitespaces and breaks inside your HTMl document.

Answer (score 0):

You could try some CSS along the lines of:

```
ul#Thumbs li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
```

And your buttons:

```
<ul id="Thumbs">
    <li><asp:ImageButton ID="btnVoteUp" Height="16px" Width="16px" runat="server"  ImageUrl="images/thumbs_up.gif" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' CommandName="VoteUp" /></li>
    <li><asp:ImageButton ID="btnVoteDown" Height="16px" Width="16px" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl="images/thumbs_down.gif" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' CommandName="VoteDown" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't work the white-space between the line items has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pull this move, it works (just ran into this issue and your perspective on the issue tipped me off)

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" /><!--
--><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat=server" />
```

the comment touching both controls is equal to them being on the same line and rendering without whitespace.

Confirmed 0px in IE7+